# Sending images from C++ to Javascript (Browser)

Tags: javascript, c++, webview, bridge

I have a project where there are a lot of thumbnails being processed in a c++ application and I use the browser to display a UI. I would like to have my thumbnails be displayed as they are being generated.
I am not sure the best way to this because so far all my attempts result in very slow performance.

I tried to convert each thumbnail to base64 and call javascript function with the string as parameter, but this was impossible since javascript parameter has a maximum size of 1024.

I tried to split thumbnails into batches and write the string to a file which then is read straight away in the loop and the image displayed, unfortunately this results in 6 seconds per 5 thumbnails which is unacceptable.

Is there any other way my problem could be solved in a good way?

Comment: This question may be a little broad for SO. Maybe you could create a server (socket) in your C++ application and serve the images directly using HTTP? You could use Javascript (Ajax?) HTTP requests to communicate the names of the thumbnails as they become available and then create <img> links to your C++ server (socket).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if socket method is faster than file io? Would save me some time to set both up and compare.

Comment: Well the easier method would be to dump the images to disk and let a dedicated web-server serve them up. In theory you may gain some speed by serving them up directly but I couldn't say how much. If its a high traffic site I doubt if you could compete with letting the web-server do it tbh.

Comment: Wait is this all hosted n the same machine? The image generation and the client browser?

Comment: Yep same machine. an iPad to be precise. Is there a benchmark of file write vs sockets somewhere? I seem to get about 500ms for writing 500 thumbnails to disk.

Comment: To be honest writing to disk is going to be much easier (quicker) to implement. I would be tempted to start with that and if its not quick enough, then try the socket method.